# CannotResolveClassException after build jar

Tags: java, xstream

I'm having a problem with this exception , but it appears when the jar id build.

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: br.com.maquinas.message.SolicitacaoEmail
```

my xml:

```
<solicitacao>
   <to>juliocesar@maquinas.com.br</to>
   <from>impressora@maquinas.com.br</from>
   <text>Envio de relatorio</text>
   <relatorio>blank_a42</relatorio>
   <titulo>rrrr</titulo>
   <formato>xls</formato>
   <parametros>
     <entry>
       <string>statusprop</string>
       <java.util.Arrays_-ArrayList>
         <a class="string-array">
           <string>000</string>
         </a>
       </java.util.Arrays_-ArrayList>
     </entry>
     <entry>
       <string>titulo</string>
       <string>rrrr</string>
     </entry>
   </parametros>
 </solicitacao>
```

my code:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("solicitacao", br.com.maquinas.message.SolicitacaoEmail.class);
SolicitacaoEmail solicitacao = (SolicitacaoEmail)xstream.fromXML(envio);
```

The development did not show any exception.

Comment: Do you start your app in IDE or .jar?

Comment: I starter with wrapper for use in Windows service. usually starts in the IDE

Comment: How do you export your project?

Comment: yes, to runnable jar and dependency in other folder

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the parameters of the wrapper, and used the manifest to run the jar to the execution of the class.